# How to query session bean pool size on websphere 8

Tags: ejb, websphere, websphere-8, session-bean

Is it possible to query current session bean pool state in websphere programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to access the pool size programmatically is to enable PMI and obtain the stats attribute of the corresponding EJB MBean.  For stateless session beans, that is the MethodReadyCount statistic of the type=StatelessSessionBean MBean.  For message-driven or entity beans, that is the PooledCount statistic of the type=MessageDrivenBean MBean.  See the [Enterprise bean counters](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rprf_datacounter1.html) topic in the Knowledge Center for more information on EJB PMI statistics.